# no error while parsing empty file yacc/lex

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc, lex

I have a parser with me generated from yacc/lex. It is working fine for all the rules I have set except one case.

If file is empty which this parser is parsing it gives error. I want to add rule so that it does not give error when file is empty. I have not added any checks for that in either of my .l/.y file.

How can this be done with YACC/LEX?

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lexer should recognize the end of input and return a token accordingly (i.e. `EOF`).

Your grammar's start rule could look like this:

```
%start program

...

program : EOF 
        | instructions EOF
        ;
```

As Ira Baxter pointed out a simple "empty" rule would also suffice. The [GNU bison manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Rpcalc-Rules) provides an example for this:

```
input   : /* empty */
        | input line
        ;
```

Comment: as you suggested i tried to recognize EOF in lexer i am foing this by 

`. {
if(yytext[0]==EOF){
return tk_eof;
}
}`
 but by debugging i came to know that this check is never true am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: I think you'd be better off using an [End-Of-File rule](http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/EOF.html#EOF).

Comment: Why can't he simply write:   "program : <yacc_epsilon> | instruction"?

Comment: @LinusKleen Thanks!! that link in your last comment helped a lot.