# Flex/Bison EOF propagation from stdin vs a file

Tags: c, bison, lex, flex-lexer

I have a scanner, parser and a main from which I create an executable via

`bison -d parser.y; flex scanner.l; gcc main.c parer.tab.c lex.yy.c`

When I run `./a.out` it does what I want: If `Ctrl+D` is pressed an `EOF` is detected and `main` can act accordingly. This means: if `yyin` is `stdin` then hitting `Return` ends the parsing of that line and the main loop waits for the next input line. Pressing `Ctrl+D` ends parsing input with a `break` in the main loop and exits. If the input comes from a file, e,g, `testFile` that file can contain 1 expression to be parsed until an EOF. In the file scenario new lines should be eaten up like spaces and tabs. All this should behave like an interpreter when input is from `stdin` and like a script evaluator when the input is from a file. An example content of such a test file would be:`test\n`. Here the EOF is not detected. And I have trouble understanding why that is the case. In other words I'd like an extension of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656786/flex-newline-scanning-for-bison) to additionally work with input files

parser.y:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

/* stuff from flex that bison needs to know about: */
int yylex();
int yyparse();
FILE *yyin;

static int parseValue;

void yyerror(const char *s);
%}

%token TWORD
%token TEOF
%token TJUNK

%start input 

%%
input: word                         {   printf("W"); parseValue =  1;   }   
    | eof                           {   printf("eof"); parseValue = -11;}
    | /* empty */                   {   printf("_"); parseValue = -1;   }   
    | error                         {   printf("E"); parseValue = -2;   }   
    ;

eof: TEOF
    ;

word: TWORD
    ;
%%

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    printf("nope...");
}

int getWord( FILE *file) {
    int err;

    if (file) {
        yyin = file;
    } else /* error */ {
        printf("file not valid");
        return -3; 
    }   

    err = yyparse();
    if (!err) {
        return parseValue;
    } else /* error */ {
        printf("parse error");
        return -4;
    }
}
```

scanner.l:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include "parser.tab.h"
#define YYSTYPE int

int yylex();
%}

/* avoid: implicit declaration of function ‘fileno’ */
/*%option always-interactive*/

%option noyywrap
/* to avoid warning: ‘yyunput’ defined but not used */
%option nounput
/* to avoid warning: ‘input’ defined but not used */
%option noinput

%%
<<EOF>>                     {   return TEOF;    }
[ \t]                       {   }
[\n]                        {   if (yyin == stdin) return 0;   }
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*        {   return TWORD; }
.                           {   return TJUNK;   }
%%
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int result = 0;
    FILE *fOut = stdout, *fIn = stdin;

    /* skip over program name */
    ++argv, --argc;
    if ( argc > 0 ) { 
        fIn = fopen( argv[0], "r" );
    }   

    while (true) {
        fprintf(fOut, "\nTEST : ", result);

        result = getWord(fIn);

        if (result == -11) {
            printf(" %i ", result); printf("--> EOF");
            break;
        }   
        if (result < 0) {
            printf(" %i ", result); printf("--> <0");
            /*continue;*/
            break;
        }   

        fprintf(fOut, " => %i", result);
    }   

    fprintf(fOut, "\n\n done \n ");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I have tried to rewrite the parse according to suggestions made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11047270/2876468) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16435621), without much success. What is correct way for main to become aware of an EOF when input is read from a file?

**Update:**
One suggestion was that the issue may be due to the `return 0;` on the `\n`. As a quick test, I only return 0 if `yyin == stin` but calling `./a.out testFile` still does not catch the `EOF`.
**Update 2:**
I got this to work via using `yywrap`. I got rid of all the `TEOF` stuff. The scanner has a part:

```
extern int eof;
```

and at the end:

```
int yywrap() {
    eof = 1;
    return 1;
}
```

In the parser there is a:

```
int eof = 0;
```

and further down in the file:

```
err = yyparse();
if (err != 0) return -4;
else if (eof) return -11;
else return parseValue;
```

If someone can show me a more elegant solution, I'd still appreciate that. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6636808/2876468) is probably a good way to make a clean version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in your links, `flex` has syntax for recognizing the end of an input file or stream (e.g., an input from a string).

In fact, `flex` effectively has such a rule operating at all times.  By default, the rule calls `yywrap`.  You turned this off (with `%noyywrap`).  That's fine, except...

The default action on encountering an "EOF token" is to return 0.

The parsers generated by bison (and byacc) need to see this zero token.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13190244/1256452) to [END OF FILE token with flex and bison (only works without it)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13189167/1256452).

Your lexer returns a `0` token on encountering a newline.  That will cause all kinds of trouble. and is no doubt leading to what you observe when reading from a file.

---

Edit: OK, with that out of the way and the update applied, let's consider your grammar.

Remember that bison adds a special production that looks for the zero-token.  Let's represent that with `$` (as people generally do, or sometimes it's `$end`).  So your entire grammar (with no actions and with "error" removed since it's also special) is:

```
$all : input $;

input: word | eof | /* empty */;

word: TWORD;

eof: TEOF;
```

which means the only sentences your grammar accepts are:

```
TWORD $
```

or:

```
TEOF $
```

or:

```
$
```

So when you call `yyparse()`, the loop inside `yyparse()` will read-ahead one token from the lexer and accept (and return) the result if the token is the zero-valued end-of-file `$`.  If not, the token needs to be one of `TWORD` or `TEOF` (anything else results in a call to `yyerror()` and an attempt to resync).  If the token is one of the two valid tokens, `yyparse()` will call the lexer once more to verify that the next token is the zero-valued end-of-file `$` token.

If all of that succeeds, `yyparse()` will return success.

Adding the actions back in, you should see `printf` output, and get a value stored in `parseValue`, based on whichever reduction rule is used to recognize the (at most one) token.

Comment: thanks, much appreciated. I'll try that out and see how that works. I'd like to upvote you, but do not have enough reputation for that...

Comment: I have removed the return 0 and the `'\n'` but the file parsing is not working; it still loops. Not sure how to proceed.

Comment: It's supposed to loop (inside `yyparse()`), until the lexer returns `0` to signal end of input.  It's been a while but as I recall flex will in fact return `0` after returning the `TEOF` token (once).  (There are a few macros to abort the parse or accept early, but you're not using them...)

Comment: Thanks again. I got this to work via the `yywrap()` function. If you have a better idea, I'd still appreciate your comments.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you want in the end, i.e., what your final language is supposed to look like, and how it's supposed to behave (differently?) when reading from stdin vs a file.  The original question says "act accordingly" but your grammar is so short that I couldn't guess at *intent*.

Comment: I hope the newly added explanation makes it clearer; let know if not.

Comment: OK, I'd suggest posting a new question, defining precisely how you want the main loop to work when reading from either a (non-stdin) file, or from stdin.  E.g., if you want `yyparse()` to return a completed parse (possibly unsuccessful) on every newline when reading stdin, vs when you want it to return only upon reaching "true EOF" when reading a file.

Comment: Thanks again, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6636808/2876468) is a good way to proceed, I think. I still can not up vote you - the question has turned into a community think and I do not get the up votes for the question any longer...

Comment: Yes, the link to the given read/eval/print loop method seems like a good way to go.